# Joining two tables and two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `articles` and `discounts` table. `Articles` could have family and subfamily (or not, could be blank).

Articles:

```
id | name | price | family | subfamily
1  | art1 | 5     | F01    | A02
2  | art2 | 5.5   | F02    |
```

Discounts

```
id | customer_id | family | subfamily | discount
1  | ABC123      | F01    | A02       | 40%
2  | CBD321      | F02    |           | 30%
```

I need to retrieve articles with their discount based on: `customer_id` (customer who will do order) family and subfamily. Articles could have discount based on his family only (subfamily is blank) or on his family and subfamily but both need to be associed to customers id on the table. If one articles doesnt match anything, his discount would be null for that customer.

How can I do this? I tried this, but only can retrieve rows as if it were `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  d.discount
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN discounts AS d
  ON a.family = d.family
  AND a.subfamily = d.subfamily
WHERE d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: `WHERE d.customer_id = 'ABC123'` is converting the `left join` to `inner join`

Comment: And if there is a discount of 30% for family F03 and 40% for subfamily F03/A33, will that subfamily get a discount of 30%, 40%, 30+40=70%, or 30x40=42%?

Comment: Is a subfamily in a family-only entry an empty string or null or a blank or something else still?

Comment: Articles's subfamily is A02 and Discounts's subfamily = A2 ???? its right or typing mistake

Comment: Your query should return art1 with 40% discount. As you say it doesn't, there must be a mismatch in family and/or subfamily. You've corrected 'A2' to 'A02'  in your example, but maybe there is still some blank or unprintable character, e.g. 'F01' <> 'F01 '. Actualyy you should have a family table and a subfamily table and foreign key constraints in articles and discounts on the two, to prevent such typos.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner First will took family/subfamily discount. If article only has family, will look for family only discount on discounts table (subfamily blank).

Comment: @ImranAliKhan yeah, typing mistake sorry, fixed.

Comment: I just notice I don't understand your data model completely. The articles table contains one record per product. Each product can belong to a product family or even a product subfamily. Correct? And the discounts table contains discounts customers get on product families and subfamilies. So there can be multiple entries for one customer, e.g. for families F01, F02, and F03 and subfamilies F03/33 and F04/A44. If a product is in family F01 the customer gets the F01 discount. If a product is in subfamily F02/A22 the customer gets the F02 discount. ...

Comment: ... If a product is in subfamily F03/A33 the customer gets the F03/A33 discount. If a product is in subfamily F03/A66 the customer gets the F03 discount. Is this so?

Comment: As to your query: please try `select * from articles where family = 'F01' and subfamily = 'A02'`  and `select * from discounts where family = 'F01' and subfamily = 'A02' and customer_id = 'ABC123'`. Do both queries return a result row? If not check your data. As mentioned, there might be a blank in the way.

Comment: And again: Is a subfamily in a family-only entry an empty string or null or a blank or something else still?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah, your are right. Discounts have multiple rows per customer with differents families/subfamilies. If a product is in family F01 and has no subfamily, the customer gets his F01 disc. If a product is in subfamily F02/A22 the customer gets his F02/A22 disc. If this customer doesn't have discount on F02/A22, that product won't have discount, nevermind if user has F02 family disc. Families and subfamilies are just strings, and discount could be by family (this means that subfamily is a blank string ('')) or by family/subfamily. Always if exists that discount for that customer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner and as I said families and subfamilies are just code strings, and row could have family and subfamiliy (or not). If only has family, subfamily will be empty string ('').

Comment: Okay, so it must be a complete match. If the product has 'F03'/'A33' then the discount entry must be on 'F03'/'A33'; if the product has 'F03'/'' then the discount entry must be on 'F03'/''. Then your query should work for customer_id = 'ABC123' and jarlh's query should work for any customer. Have you tried my queries?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner your first query returns all articles which family is 'F01' and subfamily 'A02'. Second query returns a row containing discount % of family 'F01' and subfamily 'A02' articles for ABC123 customer.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't see how your query can possibly return zero rows. It should join these records and show them.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yeah, with my query it was returning zero rows... But now with jarlh's query it seems it's working (need to test some cases still). Was because as zarruq said "WHERE d.customer_id = 'ABC123' is converting the left join to inner join". Will test ASAP and give a response. Thanks for your time!

Comment: But for customer 'ABC123' there *are* matches, so your involuntary inner join should suffice. Strange.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, tried again and yes, it was returning rows but only if had any matches on discounts table... basically an inner join. Was trying a lot of different querys and I got confused, sorry again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner well, now its working moving `WHERE` to `ON` . I have another question. If article is 'F01'/'A02' and customer has discount only on 'F01', is there any option to find in query first for 'F01'/'A02' and if doesn't have that discouunt on that subfamily find only for family ('F01'/'')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the  discounts condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT a.*, d.discount
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN discounts AS d ON a.family = d.family AND a.subfamily = d.subfamily
  AND d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. One question, is there any way to search only on condition `a.family = d.family` if `a.family = d.family AND a.subfamily = d.subfamily` doesn't match anything? Thanks.

Comment: @Roms: I suggest you accept this answer and ask the new question in a new request.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks!! Already done :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176220/how-to-case-sql-server-query