# How to "CASE" SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `articles` and `discounts` table. `Articles` could have family and subfamily (or not, could be blank).

Articles:

```
id | name | price | family | subfamily
1  | art1 | 5     | F01    | A02
2  | art2 | 4     | F01    | A03
3  | art3 | 5.5   | F02    |
```

Discounts

```
id | customer_id | family | subfamily | discount
1  | ABC123      | F01    | A02       | 40%
1  | ABC123      | F01    |           | 45%
2  | CBD321      | F02    |           | 30%
```

I need to retrieve articles with their discount based on: `customer_id` (customer who will do order) family and subfamily. Articles could have discount based on his family only (subfamily is blank) or on his family and subfamily but both need to be associed to customers id on the table. If one articles doesnt match anything, his discount would be null for that customer.

Well, to retrieve customer's articles with discounts I have this query:

```
SELECT a.*, d.discount
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN discounts AS d ON a.family = d.family AND a.subfamily = d.subfamily
AND d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
```

But as you can see, for example customer `ABC123` has discount on `'F01'/'A02'` family/subfamily and on `'F01'/''` family. So there will be no problem to get discount on `art1`, but `art2` will not match family and subfamily. Is there any way to query and search first for matches with exact family and subfamily and if there no result, search only for family? So customer `ABC123` would have 40% discount on `art1` and 45% discount on article `art2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select 
    a.*, 
    isnull(d.discount, d1.discount) as discount
from articles a
left join discounts as d 
    on a.family = d.family and a.subfamily = d.subfamily and d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
left join discounts as d1
    on a.family = d1.family and d1.subfamily = '' and d1.customer_id = 'ABC123'
;
```

Comment: I like this query for its readability. Get matching family discounts and matching subfamily discounts and give subfamily matches precedence over family-only matches. Well done. (Only, outer join criteria belongs in the `ON` clause. I've corrected this for you and moved `where d.customer_id = 'abc123'` to the two ON clauses.)

Answer (score 0):

Use order by clausule alowing both but ordering by subfamily first then use limit clausule to get the first match.

Comment: Good idea generally, but you need the better matching discount *per article*, so you cannot simply limit your results to one row. In order to make this work you'd either make it a subquery in the `SELECT` clause or use `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Either both should match OR only family should match

```
SELECT a.*, d.discount
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN discounts AS d ON (a.family = d.family AND a.subfamily = d.subfamily) OR (a.family = d.family)
AND d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is ranking. Customer ABC123 gets 40% on product family F01 generally, but for subfamily A02 it's only 40%. So F01/A02 is a better match and has hence precedence over F01.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to do the ranking:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    a.*, 
    d.discount,
    row_number() over (partition by a.id
                       order by case when a.subfamily = d.subfamily then 1 else 2 end
                      ) as rnk
  from articles a
  left join discounts d on a.family = d.family 
                        and (a.subfamily = d.subfamily or d.subfamily = '')
                        and d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

Or use `OUTER APPLY` to get the best matching discount, which I consider more elegant:

```
select a.*, d.discount
from articles a
outer apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from discounts d 
  where a.family = d.family 
    and (a.subfamily = d.subfamily or d.subfamily = '')
    and d.customer_id = 'ABC123'
  order by case when a.subfamily = d.subfamily then 1 else 2 end
) d;
```